# Gitlab error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled

Tags: gitlab, openssl

From the last macosx client I can "git clone" from my Gitlab server (last version 16, Ubuntu 22)

From Windows and git client 2.42.0.2 :

gitlab  error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled

It is a Gitlab server setup/configuration issue ? Or client option ?